# JavaFX duplication panes

Tags: javafx, duplicates

I have a game with 2 players. When it's a player's turn, the other player can't click on his pieces (which are located in a TilePane). When the player makes a play, a counter is incremented so it's easy to check whose turn it is.

```
public void switchPlayer() {
    if (this.counter % 2 == 0) {
        drawer.getBlackPane().getStyleClass().remove("play");
        drawer.getWhitePane().getStyleClass().add("play");
        drawer.getBlackPane().setDisable(true);
        drawer.getWhitePane().setDisable(false);
    } else {
        drawer.getWhitePane().getStyleClass().remove("play");
        drawer.getBlackPane().getStyleClass().add("play");
        drawer.getWhitePane().setDisable(true);
        drawer.getBlackPane().setDisable(false);
    }
}
```

The css style draws a green border around the Pane with the pieces in it of the player whose turn it is.

How could I avoid this duplication? I thought of adding a boolean and a Pane as arguments to this method but I can't seem to fix it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace the `play` css class with the `disabled` pseudoclass (see [CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node)).

E.g. (assumes you've added the `player-pane` class to the black & white panes):

```
.player-pane {
     /* style for active player pane */
}

.player-pane:disabled {
     /* style for inactive player pane */
}
```

You can also a boolean variable (+ negation) to set the `disable` property:

```
public void switchPlayer() {
    boolean whiteTurn = (this.counter % 2 == 0);

    drawer.getBlackPane().setDisable(whiteTurn);
    drawer.getWhitePane().setDisable(!whiteTurn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
private void updateTurns(Node active, Node inactive) {
    inactive.getStyleClass().remove("play");
    active.getStyleClass().add("play");
    inactive.setDisable(true);
    active.setDisable(false);
}
```

and then

```
public void switchPlayer() {
    if (this.counter % 2 == 0) {
        updateTurns(drawer.getWhitePane(), drawer.getBlackPane());
    } else {
        updateTurns(drawer.getBlackPane(), drawer.getWhitePane());
    }
}
```